# Windows 10 VM .iso

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I've been currently trying to get an VM to run Windows 10.

For some reason the Windows .iso file says "Inaccessible" after the file name, and the VM will not run

I am trying to run the x32 version of Windows 10.

Screenshot of .iso:

[image: Screenshot of .iso]

Comment: The ISO file was probably removed from disk. Make sure you have an existing file selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the VirtualBox Media Manager under the File menu or press Ctrl+D

It appears the VirtualBox thinks that your iso does not exist (or has moved/renamed).